# how to check for true/false result in alertcondition()

Tags: pine-script

I want to check if a condition is true and if it is then alert will be possible.
When I compile my code I get the following message: line 4: Cannot call 'operator >' with 'expr1'=input string. The argument should be of type: const float

Here is the code I use

```
//@version=4
study(title="myindi", shorttitle="myindi")
alertDistanceLevel = input('0', title="Alert distance level (0 = disabled)")
alertcondition((alertDistanceLevel > 0), title="distancelevel", message="distancelevel")
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your input variable `alertDistanceLevel` is a string. You have to remove the '' around the 0.